# Scala Buffer: Size or Length?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am using a mutable `Buffer` and need to find out how many elements it has.

Both `size` and `length` methods are defined, inherited from separate traits.

Is there any actual performance difference, or can they be considered exact synonyms?

Comment: I personally am a semantic nit-picker, so I only use `length` for things that are linear or sequential and `size` otherwise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are synonyms, mostly a result of Java's decision of having `size` for collections and `length` for `Array` and `String`. One will always be defined in terms of the other, and you can easily see which is which by looking at the source code, the link for which is provided on scaladoc. Just find the defining trait, open the source code, and search for `def size` or `def length`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the source code was accessible online through the scaladoc. This is quite nice!

Answer (score 5):

In this case, they can be considered synonyms. You may want to watch out with some other cases such as `Array` - whilst length and size will always return the same result, in versions prior to Scala 2.10 there may be a boxing overhead for calling `size` (which is provided by a Scala wrapper around the Array), whereas `length`  is provided by the underlying Java Array.

In Scala 2.10, this overhead has been removed by use of a value class providing the `size` method, so you should feel free to use whichever method you like.

Comment: I just profiled Scala 2.11 code, and calling `size` on an array creates an object.  You should still avoid it in performance-critical code.

Answer (score 4):

As of Scala-2.11, these methods *may* have different performance. For example, consider this code:

```
val bigArray = Array.fill(1000000)(0)
val beginTime = System.nanoTime()
var i = 0
while (i < 2000000000) {
  i += 1
  bigArray.length
}
val endTime = System.nanoTime()
println(endTime - beginTime)
sys.exit(-1)
```

Running this on my amd64 computer gives about 2423834 nanos time (varies from time to time).

Now, if I change the `length` method to `size`, it will become about 70764719 nanos time.

This is more than **20x slower**.

Why does it happen? I didn't dig it through, I don't know. But *there are* scenarios where `length` and `size` perform drastically different.

Answer (score 3):

They are synonyms, as the scaladoc for `Buffer.size` states:

> The size of this buffer, equivalent to length.

The scaladoc for `Buffer.length` is explicit too:

> The length of the buffer. Note: xs.length and xs.size yield the same result.

Simple advice: refer to the scaladoc before asking a question.

**UPDATE**: Just saw your edit adding mention of performance. As Daniel C. Sobral aid, one is normally always implemented in term of the other, so they have the same performance.

Comment: I was actually wondering if there was any performance difference? For example, one stored as an actual attribute in the data structure, versus the other one having to loop through all values (like with a List) to return the same value.