# Is the best Scala convention to invoke collection.size or collection.length

Tags: scala

I understand these two methods are identical (one is defined in terms of the other) according to this previous question:

[Scala Buffer: Size or Length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733833/scala-buffer-size-or-length)

But is there a reigning best practice or recommended convention?  I can think of three options:

(1) Always use `size`

(2) Always use `length`

(3) Use `size` for all collections exception Array

I'm leaning towards (1) or (3).  The rationale behind (3) is that these methods are inherited from Java.  And in Java you'd be invoking `collection.size()` and `array.length`.  The argument for (1) is that it builds on and simplifies (3).  The argument for (2) I'm not really sure about.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same.  It makes no difference.  Use whatever you want.