# Do size and length in Scala collections generate the same byte code?

Tags: scala

I understand that these methods may be considered "equivalent" or "synonyms", albeit not "identical", according to questions such as [Is the best Scala convention to invoke collection.size or collection.length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19671609/1296806) and [Scala Buffer: Size or Length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14733833/1296806).

But does that mean they are the same?

Don't offer me opinions or wishy-washy notions of sameness.  Just tell me when they're not actually the same.

Back up your claim with hard science!

Byte code will suffice.  I'm not so interested in JIT-specific optimizations.

I'm especially interested in the current state of the world, namely, Scala 2.11 in recent milestones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String and Array are still wrapped for size in 2.11.

You should train your fingers to type `s.length` and `arr.length`.

That's not hard, because both strings and arrays have length.

Someone coming to Scala from Java will often decide whether to use the methods on `java.lang.String` or the convenient augmentations.  Since we have a finite "decision budget" before we are required to [replenish it with donuts](http://seriouspony.com/blog/2013/7/24/your-app-makes-me-fat) from the break room, it's worth making a few of these decisions up front as a policy matter.

In case one has nothing better to discuss at lunch, or over donuts:

```
22: invokevirtual #41                 // Method scala/Predef$.augmentString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
25: invokespecial #44                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
28: invokevirtual #47                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.size:()I


18: invokevirtual #39                 // Method scala/Predef$.intArrayOps:([I)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
21: invokeinterface #44,  1           // InterfaceMethod scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.size:()I
```

Wait, wait, with -optimise you can lose the augmentString.

It's `GenSeqLike` that introduces `length` and specifies that it "yields the same result" as `size`.  `SeqLike` implements it that way.

In fact, `String` acquires a `size` method by augmentation to a `SeqLike`, specifically, `StringLike`.  That requires wrapping.  In fact, it's not easy to predict which calls require wrapping, or dispatch to an extension method.

For instance, `length` is defined in a way that wrapping is not required.  That's because `StringOps` is a value class.  In fact, it compiles to `String.length`.

However, the `apply` method on `StringOps`, defined as a call to `charAt` to mimic an array apply, though defined in the same way, calls the extension method.

(A few opcodes and allocations may not mean much after JIT compilation, of course.)

```
scala> val s = "hello"
s: String = hello

scala> val n = s.length ; val i = s.size ; val c = s(4) ; s.slice(0,4)
n: Int = 5
i: Int = 5
c: Char = o
res0: String = hell

scala> :javap -prv -
  public $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=5, locals=7, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #32                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: putstatic     #34                 // Field MODULE$:L$line4/$read$$iw$$iw$;
         8: aload_0       
         9: getstatic     #39                 // Field $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
        12: invokevirtual #42                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.s:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

`length`:

```
        15: invokevirtual #47                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
        18: putfield      #22                 // Field n:I
        21: aload_0
```

`new StringOps`, or `StringOops`:

```
        22: new           #49                 // class scala/collection/immutable/StringOps
        25: dup           
        26: getstatic     #54                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
        29: getstatic     #39                 // Field $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
        32: invokevirtual #42                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.s:()Ljava/lang/String;
        35: astore_2      
        36: astore_1      
        37: aload_2
```

`StringOps.size`:

```
        38: invokespecial #57                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        41: invokevirtual #60                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.size:()I
        44: putfield      #25                 // Field i:I
        47: aload_0       
        48: getstatic     #65                 // Field scala/collection/immutable/StringOps$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps$;
        51: getstatic     #54                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
        54: getstatic     #39                 // Field $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
        57: invokevirtual #42                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.s:()Ljava/lang/String;
        60: astore        4
        62: astore_3      
        63: aload         4
        65: iconst_4
```

`apply` extension method:

```
        66: invokevirtual #69                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps$.apply$extension:(Ljava/lang/String;I)C
        69: putfield      #28                 // Field c:C
        72: aload_0       
        73: getstatic     #65                 // Field scala/collection/immutable/StringOps$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps$;
        76: getstatic     #54                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
        79: getstatic     #39                 // Field $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
        82: invokevirtual #42                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.s:()Ljava/lang/String;
        85: astore        6
        87: astore        5
        89: aload         6
        91: iconst_0      
        92: iconst_4
```

and `slice`:

```
        93: invokevirtual #73                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps$.slice$extension:(Ljava/lang/String;II)Ljava/lang/String;
        96: putfield      #31                 // Field res0:Ljava/lang/String;
        99: return
```

Comment: You talk to yourself ..? ;)

Comment: @senia compare offsets 38 and 66. Feel free to explain it to me and I will accept your answer. I didn't have time to annotate further, as I was pressed for time.

Comment: You are correct. Only methods implemented in `StringOps` itself can be used without creation of wrapper. I didn't know that.