# Efficient string concatenation in Scala

Tags: performance, scala

The JVM optimzes String concatenation with `+` and replaces it with a `StringBuilder`. This should be the same in Scala. But what happens if strings are concatenated with `++=`?

```
var x = "x"
x ++= "y"
x ++= "z"
```

As far as I know this methods treats strings like char seqences, so even if the JVM would create a `StringBuilder` it would lead to many method calls, right? Would it be better to use a StringBuilder instead?

To what type is the String converted implicitly?

Comment: Can you unaccept my answer and pick either som-snytt or Rex Kerr?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the inconvenient truth is `StringOps` usually remains an allocation:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Concat {
    var x = "x"
    x ++= "y"
    x ++= "z"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Concat

scala> :javap -prv Concat
Binary file Concat contains $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Concat
  Size 1211 bytes
  MD5 checksum 1900522728cbb0ed0b1d3f8b962667ad
  Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Concat
  SourceFile: "<console>"
[snip]


  public $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$Concat();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=6, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #19                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: ldc           #20                 // String x
         7: putfield      #10                 // Field x:Ljava/lang/String;
        10: aload_0       
        11: new           #22                 // class scala/collection/immutable/StringOps
        14: dup           
        15: getstatic     #28                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
        18: aload_0       
        19: invokevirtual #30                 // Method x:()Ljava/lang/String;
        22: invokevirtual #34                 // Method scala/Predef$.augmentString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        25: invokespecial #36                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        28: new           #22                 // class scala/collection/immutable/StringOps
        31: dup           
        32: getstatic     #28                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
        35: ldc           #38                 // String y
        37: invokevirtual #34                 // Method scala/Predef$.augmentString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        40: invokespecial #36                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        43: getstatic     #28                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
        46: invokevirtual #42                 // Method scala/Predef$.StringCanBuildFrom:()Lscala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom;
        49: invokevirtual #46                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.$plus$plus:(Lscala/collection/GenTraversableOnce;Lscala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        52: checkcast     #48                 // class java/lang/String
        55: invokevirtual #50                 // Method x_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

See more demonstration at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826533/1296806).

Edit: To say more, you're building the String on each reassignment, so, no you're not using a single `StringBuilder`.

However, the optimization is done by `javac` and not the JIT compiler, so to compare fruits of the same kind:

```
public class Strcat {
    public String strcat(String s) {
        String t = " hi ";
        String u = " by ";
        return s + t + u;    // OK
    }
    public String strcat2(String s) {
        String t = s + " hi ";
        String u = t + " by ";
        return u;            // bad
    }
}
```

whereas

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :se -Xprint:typer

scala> class K { def f(s: String, t: String, u: String) = s ++ t ++ u }
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <console>
def f(s: String, t: String, u: String): String = scala.this.Predef.augmentString(scala.this.Predef.augmentString(s).++[Char, String](scala.this.Predef.augmentString(t))(scala.this.Predef.StringCanBuildFrom)).++[Char, String](scala.this.Predef.augmentString(u))(scala.this.Predef.StringCanBuildFrom)
```

is bad.  Or, worse, to unroll Rex's explanation:

```
  "abc" ++ "def"

  augmentString("abc").++[Char, String](augmentString("def"))(StringCanBuildFrom)

  collection.mutable.StringBuilder.newBuilder ++= new WrappedString(augmentString("def"))

  val b = collection.mutable.StringBuilder.newBuilder
  new WrappedString(augmentString("def")) foreach b.+=
```

As Rex explained, `StringBuilder` overrides `++=(String)` but not `Growable.++=(Traversable[Char])`.

In case you've ever wondered what `unaugmentString` is for:

```
    28: invokevirtual #40                 // Method scala/Predef$.augmentString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    31: invokevirtual #43                 // Method scala/Predef$.unaugmentString:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    34: invokespecial #46                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/WrappedString."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

And just to show that you do finally call unadorned `+=(Char)` but after boxing and unboxing:

```
  public final scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder apply(char);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: getfield      #19                 // Field b$1:Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
         4: iload_1       
         5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.$plus$eq:(C)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
         8: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       9     0  this   L$line10/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1;
               0       9     1     x   C
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0

  public final java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: aload_1       
         2: invokestatic  #35                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToChar:(Ljava/lang/Object;)C
         5: invokevirtual #37                 // Method apply:(C)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
         8: areturn       
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0       9     0  this   L$line10/$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1;
               0       9     1    v1   Ljava/lang/Object;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
```

A good laugh does get some oxygen into the bloodstream.

Answer (score 16):

There is a huge **HUGE** difference in time taken.

If you add strings repeatedly using `+=` you do *not* optimize away the `O(n^2)` cost of creating incrementally longer strings.  So for adding one or two you won't see a difference, but it doesn't scale; by the time you get to adding 100 (short) strings, using a StringBuilder is over 20x faster.  (Precise data: 1.3 us vs. 27.1 us to add the string representations of the numbers 0 to 100; timings should be reproducible to about += 5% and of course are for my machine.)

Using `++=` on a `var` `String` is far far worse yet, because you are then instructing Scala to treat a string as a character-by-character collection which then requires all sorts of wrappers to make the String look like a collection (*including boxed character-by-character addition using the generic version of `++`!*).  Now you're 16x slower again on 100 additions!  (Precise data: 428.8 us for `++=` on a var string instead of `+=`'s 26.7 us.)

If you write a single statement with a bunch of `+`es then the Scala compiler will use a StringBuilder and end up with an efficient result (Data: 1.8 us on non-constant strings pulled out of an array).

So, if you add strings with anything other than `+` in line, and you care about efficiency, use a `StringBuilder`.  Definitely don't use `++=` to add another `String` to a `var` `String`; there just isn't any reason to do it, and there's a big runtime penalty.

(Note--very often you don't care at all how efficient your string additions are!  Don't clutter your code with extra `StringBuilder`s unless you have reason to suspect that this particular code path is getting called a lot.)

Comment: I'm too lazy to time it, but I don't believe `++=` is char-by-char; @om-nom-nom is right about "plain old append", since TraversableLike's ++ delegates to the builder. Maybe it didn't always; like before 2.10.

Comment: My new favorite Odersky commit message (on TraversableLike): `Massive redesign so that: scala> "hi" == "hi".reverse.reverse`. That sounds almost paulp-like. (I should have said TL always used the builder's ++=, and StringBuilder overrode it for 2.10.)

Comment: @som-snytt - `StringBuilder` overrides `++=` for `String` only, but here it's typed as a `Builder[Char, String]` so it uses the generic path--and anyway it is passed an argument which is only known to be a `GenTraversableOnce[Char]`, so it goes through the whole unoptimized path.

Comment: @deamon - I _did_ benchmark it.  See timings in my post.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I'll have to get out my special glasses and look at it again.

Comment: Rex, I didn't think anything could be crazier than the Settings hierarchy in terms of crazy-to-weight ratio. But I guess some things are not worth specializing.