# Scala String Coding and Performance

Tags: scala

Could anyone please let me know what is the best way to concat string in scala? We have +, concat() etc. Which one gives better performance? Thanks!

Comment: `+` is just an alias for `concat` - Anyways, if you are going to contact only two that is fine, if you need to contact many and you know all of them then better use a string interpolator. Otherwise use a `StringBuilder`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient string concatenation in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628257/efficient-string-concatenation-in-scala)